# Python: logarithm to base 2 in nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this list:

```
mylist = [['A',5,6,7],['C',3,90,5.3],['G',5,4,6]]
```

How I can get the logarithm to base 2 in such nested lists?

This is my approach:

```
from math import log
print([log(x,2) for x in mylist2[1:]])
```

Outputs should be like:

```
[['A',2.321928094887362, 2.584962500721156, 2.807354922057604],['C',1.5849625007211563, 6.491853096329675, 2.4059923596758366],['G',2.321928094887362, 2.0, 2.584962500721156]]
```

Comment: what does your approach end with? take a look at `math` module from Python standard library, especially at [`math.log2` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2)

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Same as input, except `log` base 2 for each integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly clear on how you want your output to be formatted. But if you want to keep it in the same "format" as the input, here's a quick one-liner:

```
In [6]: list(map(lambda row: [row[0]] + [log(item, 2) for item in row[1:]], mylist))
Out[6]:
[['A', 2.321928094887362, 2.584962500721156, 2.807354922057604],
 ['C', 1.5849625007211563, 6.491853096329675, 2.4059923596758366],
 ['G', 2.321928094887362, 2.0, 2.584962500721156]]
```

If you just want the `log` values without the "key" to start each list, leave off the `[row[0]] +` part.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach (*not in computational terms obviously*) is a naive solution like this:

```
from math import log

mylist = [['A',5,6,7],['C',3,90,5.3],['G',5,4,6]]

for numbers in mylist:
  for number in numbers[1:]:
    print log(number,2) #or assign to something
```